# What is the meaning/justification for the matching conditions in the WKB approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, approximations, semiclassical

Consider the time-independent Schrodinger equation in one dimension with a potential $V(x)$ at fixed energy $E$. In the WKB approximation, we obtain solutions in the classically allowed region (i.e. where $E>V(x)$) of the form
$$\psi_{\pm}(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{p(x)}}\text{exp}(\pm \frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{x_0}^{x}p(s) ds )$$
where $$p(x) = \sqrt{2m(E-V(x))}$$
and in the classically forbidden region (i.e. where $E<V(x)$) of the form
$$\psi_{\pm}(x) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{q(x)}}\text{exp}(\pm \frac{1}{\hbar} \int_{x_0}^{x}q(s) ds )$$
where $$q(x) = \sqrt{2m(V(x)-E)}.$$

In the case where we can exactly solve the Schrodinger equation, we "match" the wavefunctions in the classically forbidden and allowed regions by making the values of $\psi,\psi'$ are the same from the left and the right at a classical turning point, say $x=a$. In the WKB approximation we perform an analogous matching process. It is complicated by the fact that the WKB wavefunctions always diverge at the turning point. Therefore we approximate the wavefunction at the turning point by an Airy function and make sure the value of the WKB wavefunctions as $x \to a$ and Airy function for large arguments are matched.

My questions are as follows:

1. What does it **mean** to match the WKB wavefunctions at the classical turning point? In the case where we solve the Schrodinger exactly, it means requiring that $\psi$ is a smooth function at that point. But clearly this is not the case for matching WKB wavefunctions. It seems to me that it means that the WKB wavefunctions on each side of $x=a$ are matched in an asymptotic sense to the Airy function.
2. **What** is being matched? People usually talk as if we want to match the WKB wavefunctions to each other, and that the Airy functions only enter the analysis in order to achieve this. However, the only sense in which I can understand the WKB wavefunctions being matched to one another is that they are matched to the Airy functions (which approximate the exact solution around $x=a$). So what are we really trying to match? The WKB wavefunctions to each other, or the WKB wavefunctions to the exact solution around $x=a$?
3. **Why** do the wavefunctions need to be matched? I understand that the exact wavefunction must be smooth in order to be a bona fide solution to the Schrodinger equation, and this is the reason for the matching in the case of an exact solution. But the WKB wavefunction is not seeking to be an exact solution to the Schrodinger equation, and can never be smooth. It seems to me that the justification for the "matching" condition must therefore be different for the WKB approximation. The best justification I can think of is that it ensures that the WKB solution is as accurate as possible around the point $x=a$. With this justification, the fact that the WKB wavefunctions on either side of $x=a$ are "matched" is just a by-product, rather than being the primary motivation, which would seem a little odd because this is not how textbooks typically motivate the matching conditions.

I should add that I'm happy with the mathematics involved but what I'm not clear about is the conceptual nature of the matching conditions and their justification.

Comment: The answer to your second problem is that in fact we match WKB wave function in both side to the airy function solution. The reason we need to match them because WKB approximation fails near x=a, so we divide the total area into three region, and in every region the approximations (WKB or linear potential) are good,  and yields approximately the true smooth wave function so should be well connected.